# Unable to retrieve an item from a tuple/struct type value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am unable to retrieve a particular item from a tuple/struct type value in pandas dataframe. I am able to accomplish the same thing using pyspark dataframe.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType,IntegerType
# import pandas as pd
dataStruct = [(("James","","Smith"),"36636","M","3000"), \
      (("Michael","Rose",""),"40288","M","4000"), \
      (("Robert","","Williams"),"42114","M","4000"), \
      (("Maria","Anne","Jones"),"39192","F","4000"), \
      (("Jen","Mary","Brown"),"","F","-1") \
]
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
schemaStruct = StructType([
        StructField('name', StructType([
             StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
             StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
             StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
             ])),
          StructField('dob', StringType(), True),
         StructField('gender', StringType(), True),
         StructField('salary', StringType(), True)
         ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=dataStruct, schema = schemaStruct)
# df.printSchema()
df.select("name.firstname").show()

pandasDF2 = df.toPandas()
display(pandasDF2["name['firstname']"])
```

Error Output : -

[image: Error]

I am able to select "firstname" from a tuple using pyspark dataframe.

But after converting it into a pandas dataframe I am also unable to retrieve the same thing
using below command : -

```
display(pandasDF2["name.firstname"])
```

I will be helpful if I can accomplish the same in pandas. Retrieving an item from a tuple/struct value in pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion of pyspark dataframe into pandas dataframe will result in translation of the `StructType` into `Row` type (`pyspark.sql.types.Row`). So in order to access the attributes of `Row` you have to use proper lookup method, this can be achieved by using a simple lambda function or the `itemgetter` method:

```
from operator import itemgetter

pandasDF2['name'].map(itemgetter('firstname'))
```

---

```
0      James
1    Michael
2     Robert
3      Maria
4        Jen
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked with both lambda function and itemgetter function.

Comment: display(pandasDF2["name"].map(lambda x : x["firstname"])) # using lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can get a tuple/list item within a Pandas Series.
Have you tried parsing the tuple?
`display(tuple(pandasDF2['name'])`

Also, before trying to manipulate the data, you should know what kind of value is it:
`display(type(pandasDF2['name']))`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).